# Calculate 2.5% below and 2.5% above the mean in Python

Tags: python, mean, population

How do I print the dataframe, where the population is within 5% of the mean? (2.5% below and 2.5% above)

Here is what I've tried:

```
mean = df['population'].mean()
minimum = mean - (0.025*mean)
maximum = mean + (0.025*mean)

df[df.population < maximum]
```

Comment: Python doesn't _have_ dataframes. If you're using Pandas, please always include the [tag:pandas] tag as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.loc[(df['population'] > minimum) & (df['population'] < maximum)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("fileName.csv")
#suppose this dataFrame contains the population in the int format
mean = df['population'].mean()
minimum = mean - (0.025*mean)
maximum = mean + (0.025*mean)

ans = df.loc[(df['population']>minimum) & (df['population'] <maximum)]
ans
```

you can use this

Answer (score 0):

I built this dataframe for testing.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

random_data = np.random.randint(1_000_000, 100_000_000, 200)

random_df = pd.DataFrame(random_data, columns=['population'])

random_df
```

Here's the answer to specifically what you were asking for.

```py
pop = random_df.population
top_boundary = pop.mean() + pop.mean() * 0.025
low_boundary = pop.mean() - pop.mean() * 0.025

criteria_boundary_limits = random_df.population.between(low_boundary, top_boundary)

criteria_boundary_df = random_df.loc[criteria_boundary_limits]

criteria_boundary_df
```

But, maybe, another answer could be had by using quantiles. I used 40 quantiles because 1/40 = 0.025.

```py
groups_list = list(range(1,41))

random_df['groups'] = pd.qcut(random_df['population'], 40, labels = groups_list)

criteria_groups_limits = random_df.groups.between(20,21)
criteria_groups_df = random_df.loc[criteria_groups_limits]

criteria_groups_df
```